# Controlling join order in combining left join and inner join in Impala SQL

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join, impala

With this kind of data

```
create table table_a as select 1 as id1;
insert into table_a values (2),(3);

create table table_b as select 1 as id1, 'a' as id2;
insert into table_b values (1,'b');

create table table_c as select 'a' as id2;
```

I have the following kind of join in Impala sql:

```
   select *
     from table_a as a
left join table_b as b
       on b.id1 = a.id1
left join table_c as c
       on c.id2 = b.id2
```

yielding this result

```
"id1","id1","id2","id2"
1,1,b,
1,1,a,a
2,,,
3,,,
```

I would like the second join to be inner join instead of left join:

```
   select *
     from table_a as a
left join table_b as b
       on b.id1 = a.id1
     join table_c as c   /* <- How to process this join first without using inner queries? */
       on c.id2 = b.id2
```

and get this result:

```
"id1","id1","id2","id2"
1,1,a,a
2,,,
3,,,
```

Thus, I would like the inner join of `table_b` and `table_c` to take place first and only after to do the left join between `table_a` and (`table_b` inner joined to `table_b`).

Is possible to determine the join order in such manner without using inner queries?

Comment: Join chains are evaluated from left to right. Use parentheses.

Comment: Your request makes no sense.  The `on` condition between `b` and `c` is going to turn the `left join` into an inner join.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added data sample and desired results. I have never used parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @jarlh, I realized left-to-right processing of joins and then found that it is possible to use RIGHT joins:

```
    select *
      from table_c as c
      join table_b as b
        on b.id2 = c.id2
right join table_a as a
        on a.id1 = b.id1;
```

in order to get the desired result:

```
"id2","id1","id2","id1"
a,1,a,1
,,,2
,,,3
```